# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php

i purchased a script from codecanyon.
when i open i got an error like this !!

Warning: require(/storage/ssd3/645/20181645/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd3/645/20181645/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 78

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/storage/ssd3/645/20181645/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd3/645/20181645/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 78

how can i fix it? i never get any answer from google

Comment: What do you mean when you say “when I open” it? Do you mean when you installed it on your site? Did it come with instructions? Your best bet is to contact the person you bought this from, or possibly Code Canyon.

Comment: It looks like you need to run "composer install".   Take a look at https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it says that it can not find a script bootstrap file.  prolly somm is wrong with dir